# ¿Por qué se cerró como demasiado amplia "Pasar oraciones por voz a texto C#"?

Tags: discusión, revisión-de-pregunta

No es el primer caso que noto, pero para eso escribiré otro post mas tarde.

Ahora, mas allá de que OP vuelva o no, me gustaría saber los motivos por el cual se considera a esta pregunta como demasiado amplia:

[Pasar oraciones por voz a texto c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87770/pasar-oraciones-por-voz-a-texto-c)

Siendo que la misma, esta completa, y OP se tomo el trabajo de ir agregando todas las cosas que se le pidieron.

Tal vez el cierre se debió a desconocimiento del lenguaje. Pero mas allá que yo no conozca la clase que esta usando, la pregunta estaría completa y es decente.

Comment: Si ya está completa, se debería nominar para reapertura. Precisamente para eso se votan, para que las arreglen.

Comment: Estaba completa antes que la cerraran.. ;)

Comment: Eso es muy relativo, casi siempre una opinión personal. Pero eso se tiene que nominar para reapertura, para que se valore nuevamente.

Comment: No no. Nunca estuvo incompleta. Es mas la unica aclaracion la pedi yo y era redundante.. por eso pregunto..

Comment: Si. Cinco personas, no una, no dos, no tres, cinco personas consideramos que si. Si consideras que ya está completa o que en tu opinión siempre estuvo completa, solo tienes que nominarla para reapertura. Es el procedimiento. Siempre lo ha sido.

Comment: Dejame revisar bien el historial y te contesto

Comment: Ahora serían cuatro, quitando a Dev Joel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La pregunta en su primera edición no era buena. Se entiende el cierre:

> ## pasar oraciones por voz a texto c
>
> estoy terminando una aplicación de reconocimiento de voz en c#, pero
> me reconoce solo palabras, además que algunas no son las que hablo,
> quisiera que me ayuden para que pueda reconocer frases, oraciones.
> Saludos.

Y me parece bien quien votase a cerrar eso. No es como habría actuado yo, pero me parece bien.

El problema son los votos a cerrar que se produjeron cuando la pregunta se encontraba en ediciones posteriores.
Aquí la pregunta ya incluía código mínimo y verificable. Le faltaba el "main" para ser completa. Pero eso no es más que código "boilerplate" que no aporta nada a la pregunta.
No era muy amplia. No se pide un libro sobre teoría de reconocimiento de voz. Solo cómo juntar palabras partiendo de un código que ya reconoce palabras individuales. Caso típico de pregunta concreta apta para SO.

Hubo al menos un voto que se produjo tras la cuarta edición. Estos votos son los que hay que mejorar.

Comment: es justamente mi punto...

Comment: Acabo de volver de mirar la cola de cierre. Había 5 preguntas. Me ha dado tiempo a 2. En el tiempo de revisar y escribir los comentarios ya estaban el resto resueltas. Y eso que solo somos un centenar con privilegio de cerrar/abrir. Me parece que hay quien tiene mucha prisa por conseguir medallitas.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, lo de los votos de cierre después de ediciones que  corrigen el error creo que es un tema a mejorar como dices. He observado este comportamiento algunas otras veces en preguntas cerradas por estar en inglés (que por lo demás son válidas), donde el OP la edita y termina cerrada porque 1 o 2 revisores no se percatan de la edición, o al menos eso quiero creer, no quiero pensar que es tema de medallas y que se da a "cerrar" de forma automática...

Comment: Necesitamos _audits_ de revisión y bloqueos para que la gente tome más conciencia :)

Comment: El primer voto de cierre de la revisión https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/54352 se hizo sobre [la versión 3 de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/87770/3), y los otros 3 sobre [la versión 4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/87770/4)

Comment: Me estarias dando la razon @Mariano. nadie se tomo el tiempo de mirar la pregunta o no la entendieron...

Comment: @gbianchi Sí, claro. Agregué el dato... El motivo real, habrá que preguntarle a los usuarios.

Comment: La pregunta se reabrió. Ahora se puede contestar. Digo, por experiencia, que algunos votan para cerrar muy a la ligera. Tengo varios casos de preguntas modificadas, adaptadas al _formato del sitio_ que algunos exigían y que siguen por tanto cerradas. Y no es un caso, son varios.